# What are the key differences between the main Latin verbs meaning "to kill"?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, word-comparison

I'm a student and my class laughs when we learn a new verb for "to kill". Just to list some of them:

- necare
- interficere
- extinguere

There are of course many others.

What are the key differences between these and other significant Latin words that are frequently translated "to kill"?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is an interesting question. Here are some words to add to your list: *caedere*, *occidere*, *trucidare*, *iugulare*, *concidere*, *effligere*, *mactare*, *letare*. (These are not all equivalent, though.)

Comment: Hi Distjubo!  Since I hadn't seen you make any edits to your question, and because it's a good one that we'd like to answer, I've gone ahead and edited it to ask for an overview of the key differences between these words.  Such a question works better here, but if you'd like to know something more specific about some of these words, or a particular context, please let us know!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nathaniel. I don't really have much time atm, especially not for latin. So thank you for helping me with this, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The thesauri and dictionaries offer marvelous help with some of these.

Adapted from Döderlein's *Hand-book of Latin Synonymes*:

> 1. *Interficere* and *perimere* are the most general expressions for **putting to death**, in whatever manner, and from whatever motive, but *interficere* as a usual, *perimere* as an old, forcible, poetical expression.
> 2. *Interimere* involves the accessory notion of privacy, as to **remove out of the way**; [Cic. Tusc. v. 20. *Dionysius alterum jussit interfici, quia viam demonstravisset interimendi sui.*]
> 3. *necare*, that of injustice, or, at least, cruelty, to **murder**.  [Curt. ix. 7, 8. *Boxum protinus placuit interfici; Biconem etiam per cruciatus necari*.]
> 4. *Occidere*, *jugulare*, *trucidare*, *obtruncare*, *percutere*, denote a sanguinary death-blow; *occidere* means by **cutting down**, especially the business of the soldier in honorable open battle;
> 5. *jugulare*, by **cutting the throat** or neck, or rather by a skilfully-directed thrust into the collar-bone, especially the business of the bandit, after the pattern of the gladiator;
> 6. *obtruncare* means to **butcher**, **massacre**, and **cut to pieces**, after the manner of the awkward murderer; [Sallust. Fr. *Cæteri vice pecorum obtruncantur*; so that you may see a mangled mass of limbs, as in the heap of slain in a battle.]
> 7. *trucidare*, to **slaughter** as one would a steer, after the manner of the blood-thirsty miscreant, who, without meeting with resistance, plays the hero on the defenceless; [Tac. Hist. *Juberet interfici; offerre se corpora iræ; trucidaret*.]
> 8. *percutere*, to **execute**, as a mere mechanical act, after the manner of the headsman, or other executioner of a sentence of condemnation, or, at least, of a death-warrant.  [Cic. Cat. iv. 6. and Rosc. Am. 34. *Cujus consilio occisus sit invenio; cujus manu percussus sit non invenio*.]

And adapted from Smith's *Copious and Critical English-Latin Dictionary*:

> **kill:**
>
> 1. *interficio* (most general term).
> 2. *cædo* (to cut or beat, whether to death or not; to kill by wounds or blows). **To slay**.
> 3. *neco* (by wicked and cruel means; as, assassination, poison). **To murder**.
> 4. *occido* (to cut down, esp. in battle). **To slay**.
> 5. *trucido* (to kill violently and ruthlessly). **To butcher**.
> 6. *interimo* (to do away with, cut off). **To destroy**.
> 7. *obtrunco* (to cut down, esp. in the way of murder or assassination). **To slaughter**.

I must say, as a spoken-Latin advocate, that, while Latin can be frustrating when you want to talk about things like a malfunctioning ATM or the difficulty one has signing up for a [user account](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/742/what-is-user-account-in-latin), when you're as angry a person as I am it's quite useful to have so many words with which to imagine people's violent ends.

Comment: I formatted your citations to be a little more readable--it's a great list!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the formatting—that makes it a lot more helpful.

Comment: Really nice. I mean our latin teacher only taught us "to kill" for all of those words.  Really helpful.

Comment: Oh, I'm glad! Why don't you wait a few days to see whether somebody else comes up with an even better answer and then accept the one you find the most helpful?

Comment: Looks like theres no one who wants to compete with this answer :D

Comment: Ah, well. Usually it's other folks who post the answers with which I don't want to compete, so this is a nice change of pace for me. :)