# "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them" in Latin

Tags: contemporary-latin, sentence-translation

I was planning to enhance a bit my profile here, and I thought of using the default StackExchange message, only in Latin.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=es&tab=wT&authuser=0#en/la/Apparently%2C%20this%20user%20prefers%20to%20keep%20an%20air%20of%20mystery%20about%20them.) turns the well known:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

into this:

> Videtur quod hoc sacramentum ex aere, circa user potius ut per eas.

I understand the limitations of a tool like Google Translate and appreciate it for what it is, but, what would be a real translation of:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

I made some attempts of translating it by myself from the Google example, but the metaphor of "keep an air of mystery about" is just too much for me.

Comment: Recall the cardinal rule of (Latin) Google translate: uti est decipi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Translate is actually slightly less wrong than usual! It got "apparently" correct.

Off the top of my head, I would say:

> *Vidētur malle tenēre sibi auram mystēriōsam.*
>   He/she seems to prefer to keep a mysterious air about him/her.

*Vidētur* is the passive of *videt* "he/she sees"; in the passive, it means "he/she seems". *Malle* means "to prefer" and takes an infinitive, *tenēre* means "to hold", *sibi* means "to him/herself".

I'm not fully happy with either of the last two words, though; I chose them to look similar to the English ones but the meanings aren't quite the same.

*Auram* is accusative of *aura* which is a Greek borrowing that literally means "breeze" (related to "air"). According to Lewis and Short it can also mean something closer to the English meaning of "aura".

And *mystēriōsam* is "pertaining to a *mystērium*", which originally meant a religious mystery (think the Eleysinian Mysteries) but later came to mean any secret thing. There are other words for "mysterious" that are closer to the English meaning, such as *tenēbrōsus* "shadowy", but all the ones I know have rather negative connotations.

Answer (score 2):

If I may take some more freedom, I would like to use the verb *cognoscere*, meaning "to know", "to be acquainted with", "to identify", and similar.

Assuming I have understood correctly (which is not guaranteed by any means), the preferred classical adjective would be *mysticus* instead of *mysteriosus*, although both are clearly understandable.
I also prefer the former one for brevity.

I would render "apparently" with *apparet* with an accusative and an infinitive.
I think I currently favour the translation *sodalis* for "user" (there is an [older question about users and accounts](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/742/79)).

Combining these ideas leads me to:

> *Apparet hunc sodalem mystice cognosci malle.*
>   This user seems to prefer beeing seen mysteriously.

---

Let me attempt to translate what Google Translate gave you back to English:

> *Videtur quod hoc sacramentum ex aere, circa user potius ut per eas.*
>   It seems that this sacrament from air, around sodalis so that better you through go.

It is nonsensical in Latin, and I tried to keep the translation at the same level.
I am reminded of [English as she is spoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_As_She_Is_Spoke), which is usually not a good sign.
There is also a whole [question exploring the absurdity of Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4349/79) if you want details.

Comment: I have read Ben Kovitz answer, but I did not know about *English As She Is Spoke*. Reminds me of the [Dirty Hungarian Phrasebook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6D1YI-41ao).